# Audiomoths availability

Tags: fieldwork, audiomoth

I am new to this Forum so hopefully I can address my question effectively. I am a grad-student in Ecology and I am planning my field season for this summer. I am needing about 10 Audiomoths but they seem to be out of stock everywhere. Next batch will be available until August but that might be too late for my field season. Any idea where to get them second hand? rent options? I am running out of time and can't find them anywhere. Any help is welcome!

Comment: I hope that you find the Audiomoths you need, but in case you are accepting alternative approaches, what would be your required sampling frequency? what would be the required endurance?

Answer (score 1):

As you're probably aware, AudioMoths periodically go on sale on GroupGets (https://groupgets.com/campaigns/1192) - hope you got some! If not, WildLabs is a good place to contact other bioacoustics researchers: https://staging.wildlabsdev.net/groups/acoustic-monitoring